# Export content from old TYPO3 installation to latest TYPO3 version?

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3

I have to update an old TYPO3 website (version 4.3.2) to the latest version. However, I have barely ever worked with this CMS and still find it rather complicated.

Is there an easy way to move the content from the old 4.3.2 installation to a 6.2.4 installation?

Or, would it be easier to update the current installation? I read I have to update to every major version which sounds like a big pain, and the documentation no longer talks about version 4.3.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to move the content from the old 4.3.2 installation to a 6.2.4 installation?

Unfortunately no.

> Or, would it be easier to update the current installation? I read I have to update to every major version which sounds like a big pain, and the documentation no longer talks about version 4.3.2.

Version 4.3 is not supported anymore for some years. Yes, the regular way to update TYPO3 is to switch from one major version to the following major version.

But TYPO3 supports a upgrade path for LTS versions. Version 4.5 and 6.2 are such LTS versions. 
So in your case you may

1. Upgrade from 4.3 to 4.5 (Upgrade Wizard in Install Tool)
2. Upgrade all extensions
3. Install the extension smoothmigration (https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/smoothmigration) and run all tests
4. Upgrade directly to version 6.2 (Upgrade Wizard in Install Tool)
5. Upgrade remaining extensions which work with 6.2 only (if an extensions is not available for 6.2, you may want to check github for forks)
6. Check your TypoScript, the default markup for content will differ and therefore have some DIVs added or removed

Comment: Even though I second that going from 4.5 to 6.2 is recommended, also going from 4.2 or 4.3 to 6.2 directly worked fine in my case. Of course it can make you more trouble with extensions, but most extensions need to be updated anyway.